# Convertir datos tipoa tipo string

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Chicos necesito convertir un dato tipo date y otro tipo varchar a tipo string y luego que ambos esten en tipo string concartenarlos. Puedo hacer eso en plsql???

Comment: Amigo Leonardo bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] y leer [ask] para formular una pregunta de mejor calidad. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Claro. Sin problemas:

```
> select to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') || ' un dato tipo varchar'
    from dual;
```

Ejemplo, si tienes una tabla así:

```
> create table a (d date, v varchar2(200);
```

Tu query puede ser:

```
> select to_char(d, 'dd/mm/yyyy') || v
    from a;
```

En PL/SQL sería tan directo como declarar un cursor con este query, e iterarlo a una varable de tipo `varchar2`.